# How to handle dependencies string in Python

Tags: python, json, dependencies

I need to handle dependencies in the way they're explained in this link:
https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

So I need to read from a Json file and check if my dependencies are fulfilled. To check if I have a package installed I execute a query on a PostgreSQL db and see if I have a record in a table.

My question is: there's some kind of module I can use to compare version string? I checked distutils.version but it doesn't handle for example these kind of version strings:

```
{ "dependencies" :
 { "foo" : "1.0.0 - 2.9999.9999"
  , "bar" : ">=1.0.2 <2.1.2"
  , "baz" : ">1.0.2 <=2.3.4"
  , "boo" : "2.0.1"
  , "qux" : "<1.0.0 || >=2.3.1 <2.4.5 || >=2.5.2 <3.0.0"
  , "asd" : "http://asdf.com/asdf.tar.gz"
  , "til" : "~1.2"
  , "elf" : "~1.2.3"
  , "two" : "2.x"
  , "thr" : "3.3.x"
  , "lat" : "latest"
  , "dyl" : "file:../dyl"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code for this?

Comment: I haven't started coding yet, I'm just thinking about how handling these kind of version strings.

Comment: Are you specifically using npm's version string format?

Comment: yes Andrew, I was told to use the same format.